# method = 'multi' not working on the sqlalchemy package in python

Tags: python, sql, pandas, performance, sqlalchemy

i currently use sqlalchemy package and my installed package is 1.3.16. and my python version is 3.6.7. i am able to write small datasets to SQL server using sqlalchemy and to_sql, but when i try to write 1.1M row dataset to sql server, it takes a few hours. from my online research, i see that sqlalchemy has the optional parameter method= 'multi' option. but when i use it, i get the error, 'to_sql' has no parameter 'method'. here is my code. if i use the same code without 'method' parameter, it works but just painfully slow.

```
import sqlalchemy
import math

input_num_of_cols=len(input.columns)
chunknum=math.floor(2000/input_num_of_cols)

engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://@CRSQLDEV04") 
conn = engine.connect()

input.to_sql('Input',con=conn,chunksize=chunknum, method = 'multi', if_exists = 'append', index = False, schema = 'ABC.dbo')
```

any idea if its the sqlalchemy package i am using? or my python version?

Thanks in advance, Ramesh

Comment: What's more important is the version of *pandas* that you are using.

Comment: IS your problem solved?

Comment: yes, thank you so much for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

As @Gord briefly mentioned, it's the version of `pandas` that matters in this case.

> Since 0.24.0 there is a method parameter in pandas.to_sql() where you can define your own insertion function or just use `method='multi'` to tell pandas to pass multiple rows in a single INSERT query, which makes it a lot faster.

Just ensure you have the right version of `pandas`, i.e. anything above `0.24.0`

Comment: thanks for the reply. it is so much faster now. thanks,

Comment: @RameshArumugam If this answer helped in your problem, please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer. see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more information